Where is the best place to set kernel module options in Debian Linux?
Seems like I can set persistent module options in /etc/default/grub kernel boot parameters or in /etc/modprobe.d/xxxx.conf. The latter seems less messy.
Still learning Linux internals.

The best place is the place you are most comfortable with

The former would seem slightly more correct to me, as when grub is reinstalled it would read the config from that file - so installing them in /etc/default/grub will make the boot parameters available to the kernel even if its compiled in rather then a module.
That said, if its something that the kernel does not depend on to be present at boot time there is no problem adding them to xxxx.conf.
There is usually more then 1 correct way to do something under Linux.
